# Hping3 not working on BigIP target server

Tags: networking

I have a BigIP target server and try to meassure the (average) rtt. Usually I do this with  `sudo hping3 -S -p 80  <target>`.

hping3 works fine with the listed parameters for arbitrary hosts, but for this server - I know it's a F5 BigIP the tool doesn't seem to work.

I can curl the target server at port 80 and 443 and browse it and nslookup it, however
hping3 returns the following:

```
sudo hping3 -S -p 80  -VVV XXXXXXXXXX
using ens192, addr: XXXXXXXXXX, MTU: 1500
HPING XXXXXXXXXX (ens192 XXXXXXXXXX): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
^C
--- XXXXXXXXXX hping statistic ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.0/0.0/0.0 ms
```

Not even showing a single line with sent packages although using -VVV.

---

To confuse me even more the requests for port 443 result in 0.0ms responses:

```
sudo hping3 -S -p 443 XXXXXXXXXX
HPING XXXXXXXXXX (ens192 XXXXXXXXXX ): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=46 ip=XXXXXXXXXX ttl=250 DF id=52797 sport=443 flags=SA seq=0 win=4380 rtt=0.0 ms
len=46 ip=XXXXXXXXXX ttl=250 DF id=58358 sport=443 flags=SA seq=0 win=4380 rtt=0.0 ms
^C
--- XXXXXXXXXX hping statistic ---
3 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 34% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.0/0.0/0.0 ms
```

Comment: Yes thats a networking issue, but looks that your port 80 is filtered and your port 443 is responding with the corresponding SYN+ACK

Comment: Okay, I found out, that hping3 is working at another machine within the same network, it seems that this could be an issue of the esx vm and not of hping